# Can't open a website installed from CluedIn Home repo

Tags: dns, cluedin

I had a working instance of CluedIn installed from the Home repo (https://github.com/CluedIn-io/Home).
For the last few days, I can't reach it. Say, my organization name is `foobar`: when I open http://foobar.127.0.0.1.xip.io:9080/ (which used to work just fine last week), my browser can't reach the page and shows `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens when http://xip.io/ is down.
To solve the problem, please, use another wildcard DNS provider. For example, https://nip.io/.
There is only one change you need to do in the Home repo - in the `.env` file, change this line:
`CLUEDIN_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1.xip.io`
To this:
`CLUEDIN_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1.nip.io`
And then run `./cluedin.ps1 up`.

Your site will be available at http://foobar.127.0.0.1.nip.io:9080/

Answer (score 2):

Should you need to script this, you can run the following:

```
./cluedin.ps1 env -set CLUEDIN_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1.nip.io # sets for the default environment
```

or

```
./cluedin.ps1 env dev -set CLUEDIN_DOMAIN=127.0.0.1.nip.io # sets for a custom environment called dev
```

Answer (score 1):

For the Helm chart you have to update the `dns` section ..

`v3.2.2`

```yaml
global:
  dns:
    hostname: "127.0.0.1.nip.io"
```

.. or in older versions of the chart `v3.2.1` and below ..

```yaml
dns:
  hostname: "127.0.0.1.nip.io"
```

Once deployed it should restart effected pods but the `server`, `ui` and `gql` deployments might need to be restarted to pick up new configmap values.